# what is the geometric significance of covariant differentiation?

Tags: tensors

I studied tensor calculus and there is a chapter named covariant differentiation of tensors. There one defines the covariant differentiation of a rank $1$ contravariant tensor as $$A^i_{,j}=\frac{\partial A^i}{\partial x^j}+\Gamma^i_{kj}A^k$$ and that of a rank $1$ covariant tensor as $${A_i}_{,j}=\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^j}-\Gamma^k_{ij}A_k$$ and that of a rank $2$ mixed one as $$A^i_{j,k}=\frac{\partial A^i_j}{\partial x^k}+\Gamma^i_{mk}A^m_j-\Gamma^m_{jk}A^i_m$$ My question is, why we need those extra "+" and "-" adjustments accompanied by those second kind Christoffel symbols? We could have just written the first partial differentiation term as we did in vector analysis differentiation operators, like gradient, divergence, curl etc. In short, what do these Christoffel symbols add to the differentiation terms geometrically? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just take partial derivatives then the result depends on the choice of coordinate system. With covariant differentiation it does not.  For this to hold true, the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ must satisfiy certain relations when you change coordinates This means that the so defined derivative (the differentiated tensor, to be more precise) has a geometric meaning independented of the choice of coordinates, which is not true for the simple partial derivatives. There is a lot more to covariant differentiation, but this is the aspect which is relevant to your question.

Comment: (continued) in particular, the covariant derivative of a tensor field is, again, a tensor field. And, btw., what you are talking about here are tensor fields, not tensors. Tensors are objects from (linear) algebra. Tensor fields are elements of tensor bundles, which arise from applying the algebraic constructions to tangent spaces of manifolds.